# How to use not in in drupal views 3

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7 with views 3.

I need a list of students who have due payments in a view. The students who have paid the fees are stored in a new table. Now I want to show the students which are not in other table. How can I have this is views 3

EDIT Better explanation of query

I am using views 3 to get a list of students who have due payments. The students who have paid the fees are stored in a new table. Now I want to show the students which are not in fees paid table. How can I have this is views 3.

My Table structure is:

I have a table structure for fee details as

```
fid     
name    
description
currency
fee     
instalments
created
```

This fee schedule has N no of instalments and storing in a cross ref table as

```
iid
fid
instalment_no
amount
payable_by
```

This fee schedule has associated students and are storing in a cross ref table as

```
fid
uid
```

The table structure for paid students who has paid fees.

```
pid      Payment ID serial
fid      Fees ID details
iid      Instalment No
uid      Student who has paid the fees
paid_on  Payment date
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Insufficient details provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My suggestion:** You could make this a *great* deal easier for yourself if "Has payed" a field on the User entity instead.

**Answer to your question:** You need to expose the custom table to Views, by telling Views that it exists and what type of data there is in it. The canonical way of doing that is with [hook_views_data](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7), although the [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module claims to be able to do this automatically.

Once you have the data in Views, you create a View based on "User", and add a "Filter" to remove all users in the "Payed" table.

Comment: Thanks Letharion, I can not make a new field for "Has Payed" as you can see in updated question that I have N no of instalments in one payment schdule. So my logic will be to show the users with instalment due which are not in "Payments" table. In filter critaria, how can I filter records not in other table?

Comment: Not sure why you couldn't use Field API for that. Also don't knwo which part of the rest of my answer that requires clarification. :)

Comment: I have multiple instalments per payment schdule and student. I installed the data module, but there is no documentation available for the usage.